# Accessing email properties in Exchange web server managed API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm a complete newbie to EWS, but am trying to convert a happily functioning IMAP program into EWS & am having problems accessing simple fields in the managed API, e.g. From, Sender, BodyType. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong? Many thanks folks.

```
        ItemView view = new ItemView(99);
        SearchFilter.Exists filter = new SearchFilter.Exists(EmailMessageSchema.Id);
        FindItemsResults<Item> inboxMessageList = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view);
        Console.WriteLine("Inbox message count: " + inboxMessageList.TotalCount);
        int messageCounter = 1;

        //message loop
        foreach (Item thisMessage in inboxMessageList)
        {
            //Collect info about current email message
            Item thisItem = Item.Bind(service, thisMessage.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Current message ID: " + thisMessage.Id);

            string uniqueID = "EMAIL-" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss-fff");
            string messageTo = thisItem.DisplayTo;
            string messageCC = thisItem.DisplayCc;
            string messageFrom = //cant get this to work
            string messageSubject = thisItem.Subject;
            string messageDate = thisMessage.DateTimeReceived.ToString();
            int noOfAttachments = 0;
            Boolean messageHasAttachments = thisMessage.HasAttachments;
            if (messageHasAttachments) noOfAttachments = thisMessage.Attachments.Count();
            string isBodyHtml = //cant seem to implement this either
            Boolean domainblacklistResult = fn.CheckIfDomainBlacklisted(messageFrom);
            Boolean emailblacklistResult = fn.CheckIfEmailBlacklisted(messageFrom);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access information about the email message, you need to bind it as an `EmailMessage`, instead of as an `Item`. Example:

```
EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, thisMessage.Id);
```

Comment: Hi MadDev, i couldnt seem to make it work :(

Tried adding in view.PropertySet outside the foreach loop and couldnt access the properties still.

Tried extending the Item.Bind to include the third overload of PropertySet too, but that didnt work either.

Any more ideas please?? Thank you!

Comment: When you call `Item.Bind`, is `thisItem` empty? I'm not sure you even need the `Item.Bind` code. Also, note that not all items are Email Messages(there may be meeting requests etc). See [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633693(v%3Dexchg.80))

Comment: Hi MadDev, thanks again! The answer was binding it as an EmailMessage rather than as an Item. That did the trick :) Thanks!

Comment: Cool no problem :). I have updated my answer so as to help others in the future, who may come across this question. Feel free to mark it as the answer